# Additional 2px found in P element ( short fiddle )

Tags: html, css

Here is the pretty short fiddle which includes a 20px by 20px "ruler".  I expect my p tag to be 20px high...10px text, and 10 px for the top and bottom padding (5px + 5px).

However it looks to be about 22px.

http://jsfiddle.net/BNnhp/30/

I have reset the body tag, the p tag and the div tag using margin 0px, padding 0px and line-height 100%.

Previously I had as a similar issue that was fixed by setting line-height to 100%....however this is not working here?

I want to know the exact cause - CSS attribute and value.

But for testing purposes I clicked the normalize box in jsfiddle and this had no effect either.

Added in more resets here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BNnhp/32/

Comment: I had to change your font to 8px to get the paragraph to be 20px tall.

Comment: Indeed that would work...but where is that extra 2px coming from?

Comment: @j08691, that's a hack around the real issue (using `display:inline` instead of `display:block;`). See my answer for more info.

Comment: The extra pixels allow space for `q, y, p, g, j` and any other letter with dangling parts.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718299/font-size-what-can-i-be-sure-of

Comment: @bfrohs - It's no hack. I wasn't providing that as a solution; merely a comment.

Comment: What is your line-height set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [small test case](http://jsfiddle.net/BNnhp/34/), but it worked fine there. So, I went back to your answer, and found you were setting `p`'s `display` value to `inline`, which was causing the 2px - 3px difference ([fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/BNnhp/37/)). To fix, change your CSS as follows (look at comments):

```css
/* ... */
#hold_name{
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  /* position:relative; -- Don't need */
  /* top: 0px; -- Don't need */
  color:#000000;
  /* display:inline; -- Don't need */
  background: #ffffff;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin:0; /* Need to add */
  line-height:100%;
}
#hold_name:hover{
}
#wrap{    
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; /* Change to 20px from 24px */
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #007fa5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #007fa5;
  border-right: 1px solid #007fa5;
}
/* ... */
```

Comment: I don't understand why would inline cause this?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist, use my exact code. It works. See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BNnhp/37/). And the reason `inline` causes that is because [that's what inline does](http://jsfiddle.net/fZTrB/).

Comment: Requires both removal of display:inline and line-height:100% . Smaller Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BNnhp/48/

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your `font-size` is set to 10px doesn't promise you that the height would also be 10px. Some specific letters/symbols are higher than others.

If you change it to, say 8px like this:

```
#hold_name{
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

then you will notice the container size changes as well.
This is because the

tag re-sizes itself to contain the text inside.
You could set a specific height for your

as well and it would change:

```
#hold_name{
    font-size: 9px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

and that would set the containing `<p>` element to a height of 10 pixels, no matter what the font-size is.

combining with the 5px padding on top and bottom, it would sum to 10px + 5px + 5px = 20px height.

Comment: This still is a bug right..if I specify my font-height as 10px ..and it makes it 12px...that is a bug.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist, Shahar, [`font-size` can determine the `height` of the element](http://jsfiddle.net/BNnhp/34/). The position/height of characters doesn't affect the height of the line (they just simply reposition themselves).

Comment: @bfrohs `font-size` can determine the height if the elements containing that text. However, including a specific `height` for that element as well will set it's height to that fixed size, no matter what the font size is. It's not a bug, it's just how CSS treats these properties. Also there is no `font-height` property in CSS. I guess you are confusing it with `line-height` which sets the distance between different text lines.

Comment: Requires both removal of display:inline and line-height:100% . Smaller Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BNnhp/48/

Comment: @Shahar, I was calling it a hack, not because `height` doesn't work for setting the height, but because in this particular situation, the height *should* be determined by the text, as setting a static height and having larger text would make it unreadable. However, *correctly* setting the `font-size` will end with the same result in normal situations with the benefit of being able to handle a different `font-size` (e.g. zoom text). Also, if the height is changed, my solution only requires changing one value (`font-size`) rather than two (`font-size` & `height`), leaving less room for error.

Comment: @bfrohs I agree, it's a good idea to just set the font-size if you have enough room, and after visually testing in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

While taking the other answers into consideration, you can also change the padding attribute of `.menu-drop` to match the following, then add a line-height of 20px:

```
.menu_drop{    
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px; /* modified padding value */
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #bfddec;
  color: #2875DE;
  font: 11px arial;
  line-height: 20px; /* new line-height property */
}
```